# error TS2307: Cannot find module 'marked' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: angular, cypress, javascript-marked

I was performing a headless test in Cypress and had to run

`npm install --save-dev start-server-and-test` so the server can start and wait for the url to respond before running the test. And ever since I ran that command, my code has been throwing the error below. And I don't know if that's a coincidence.

```
Error: src/app/article/markdown.pipe.ts:2:25 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'marked' or its corresponding type declarations.

2 import * as marked from 'marked';
```

and this is my `markdown.pipe.ts` file:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import * as marked from 'marked';

@Pipe({name: 'markdown'})
export class MarkdownPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(content: string): string {
    return marked(content, { sanitize: true });
  }
}
```

I tried to delete the `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` then run npm install but that didn't solve the issue.
I searched similar posts here on stackoverflow and some suggestions were to run

`npm install -g marked` and `npm install --save-dev @types/marked` which had solve some similar problems, but it didn't seem to solve mine.

Here is the git repository of the folder.
https://github.com/Leealp/BugsFixed

How can I fix the issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, add types for  for the `marked` package

```js
npm install --save @types/marked
```

Inside the `index.d.ts` file you can see a couple of variations of

```js
export function marked(...
```

Which is a "named" export, not the "default" export (there is no default export)

So in `markdown.pipe.ts` import it as

```js
import {marked} from 'marked'
```

Comment: Fody After doing what you recommended, my UI stopped working. Some functionalities such as creating accounts, and signing into the app don't work anymore. How is that happening?

Comment: Those "functionalities" do not sound in any way related to the `marked` import. Something else is causing it.

Answer (score 1):

First, add types for for the marked package

```
npm install --save @types/marked
```

Next, run

```
npm install marked
```

This works for me in my project.

Answer (score 1):

I had it installed with npm....

I closed my IDE, re-opened, and it was fine

`import { marked } from 'marked'`

Answer (score 0):

as @Fody said, the simplest way to fix is to add dependency `@types/marked`

but, it caused another problem, you need to change invoke way, otherwise IDE or webpack(while packing project) would throw error

i checked the source code of `marked`, the followging way might fix your issue

```
// change before
import marked from 'marked';

...
marked(mdStr);
...

// changed
import { parse as mdParse } from 'marked/lib/marked.esm.js;

...
mdParse(mdStr);
...
```

BTW, to avoid the issue about path changed, you might need to lock the version of marked

Comment: No, that's exactly the same as using the `{marked}` export (as stated in the accepted answer). See [marked.esm.js#L2802](https://github.com/markedjs/marked/blob/2d5af8601fbd6318ea1f083fa65ab978072bb130/lib/marked.esm.js#L2802) - `const parse = marked;`